# New UI Builder/Toolkit & VR World Space

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality, unity-ui

Is it possible to use the new UI builder and Toolkit for World Space UI in Virtual Reality use?

I have seen ways of doing it with Render Textures but not only does It not seem to be the same as a World Space Canvas (Which I did expect but it´s not even close) but I also don´t find a way of interacting using the VR Raycast method?

Comment: I was about to flag this as _rant in disguise,_ but the _"smooch you on the lips"_ made my day :)

Comment: So... do you want the smooch or...?

Comment: No, but actually, I know it sounded like a rant, that was just my frustration talking lol But I actually need some help with this. I did get help in the meantime already with one good link to a script that makes this happen ( https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/qh4fe4/here_is_a_script_to_use_uitoolkit_in_runtime/ ) and several suggestions of more "traditional approaches". For now, this lead me to just get the prototype out in a traditional manner, and then probably get some tries with the script, or well, hopefully at that point, either a better solution or a Unity official Solution. :)

Comment: _"So... do you want the smooch or...?"_ - haha I'll be right thanks ;)   I'd help but I've only done a tiny bit of UI Toolkit

Answer (score 3):

This isn't officially supported yet but is certainly possible for those willing to implement it themselves.

As the OP mentioned it is straightforward enough to render the UI, the main idea is to set [panelSettings.targetTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UIElements.PanelSettings.html#UnityEngine_UIElements_PanelSettings_targetTexture) to some `RenderTexture`, which you can apply to a quad like any other texture.
Note that if you have multiple UIs you will need multiple instances of `PanelSettings`.

For raycasting there is a method [panelSettings.SetScreenToPanelSpaceFunction](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UIElements.PanelSettings.html#methods) which can be used for translating 2d coordinates to panel coordinates, here is an [Official Unity Sample](https://github.com/needle-mirror/com.unity.ui/blob/9837807be0ff6bdf12df2e2bed0cbcef7936e3d9/Samples%7E/Runtime/Rendering/UITextureProjection.cs) demonstrating how it can be implemented in camera space. The method is called every update so it *can* be hijacked to use a raycast from a controller instead of screen coordinates, although I've had mixed results with this approach.

Check out [this repo](https://github.com/katas94/WorldSpace_UIToolkit_XR) for an example implementation in XR, it is a more sophisticated solution which makes extended use of the input system.